# perl bigint not working with regexp matches

Tags: perl

I see the following log messages.  By looking at the numbers, I have a suspicion that `timeStampLastSeekPoint` is always one plus `timeInNanos`.

```
% grep -E '^java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.*timeStampLastSeekPoint' messages | head -5                              
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeInNanos=1500629929661000010, timeStampLastSeekPoint=1500629929661000011
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeInNanos=1500629929661000010, timeStampLastSeekPoint=1500629929661000011
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeInNanos=1500629929661000010, timeStampLastSeekPoint=1500629929661000011
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeInNanos=1500630763150000010, timeStampLastSeekPoint=1500630763150000011
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeInNanos=1500630763150000010, timeStampLastSeekPoint=1500630763150000011
```

To confirm my suspicion, I pipe into this perl one-liner to extract numbers and show the difference.  The differences show all 0s, which can't be true.  It is immediately clear that I need higher precision.

```
% grep -E '^java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.*timeStampLastSeekPoint' messages | \
    perl -ne 'if (/timeInNanos=(\d+), timeStampLastSeekPoint=(\d+)/) { printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", $1, $2, $2 - $1) }' | head -5      
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 0
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 0
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 0
1500630763150000010 1500630763150000011 0
1500630763150000010 1500630763150000011 0
```

I googled, found the `bigint` module, and tried it.  However, it still doesn't work.

```
% grep -E '^java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.*timeStampLastSeekPoint' messages | \
    perl -Mbigint -ne 'if (/timeInNanos=(\d+), timeStampLastSeekPoint=(\d+)/) { printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", $1, $2, $2 - $1) }' | head -5                                 
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 0                                                                                   
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 0
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 0
1500630763150000010 1500630763150000011 0
1500630763150000010 1500630763150000011 0
```

After a few attempts, I find that it works only after the regexp matches are assigned to regular variables.  As an aside, I now confirm my suspicion that the diff is always 1.

```
% grep -E '^java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.*timeStampLastSeekPoint' messages | \
    perl -Mbigint -ne 'if (/timeInNanos=(\d+), timeStampLastSeekPoint=(\d+)/) { printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", $1, $2, ($b=$2) - ($a=$1)) }' | head -5                       
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 1                                                                                   
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 1
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 1
1500630763150000010 1500630763150000011 1
1500630763150000010 1500630763150000011 1
```

All good now that I find the workaround.  However, it is not intuitive why the assignments are necessary.  Shouldn't `$2 - $1` just work?  It feels like a bug.  Or, is there an explanation to understand that this is a reasonable behavior?  The perl version is v5.14.2.

Comment: btw, the "`l`" in "`%ld`" is meaningless in Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`use bigint;` has no effect on your program because it only affects numeric literals, and your program has none.

`use bigint;` effectively replaces numeric literals with `Math::BigInt->new("LITERAL")`. This means that

```
use bigint;

2
```

is equivalent to

```
use Math::BigInt qw( );

Math::BigInt->new("2")
```

This presents a solution:

```
use Math::BigInt qw( );

Math::BigInt->new($2) - Math::BigInt->new($1)
```

But thanks to overloaded operators, you could simply use

```
use Math::BigInt qw( );

Math::BigInt->new($2) - $1
```

or

```
use bigint;

0 + $2 - $1
```

In all cases, you want to use `%s` (not `%d`) to have M::BI stringify the num
instead of having it numify to an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  I didn't know `use bigint` only affects numeric literals.  I am puzzled how `($b=$2) - ($a=$1)` solves it (I just confirmed that it works without `-Mbigint`).  I thought `bigint` did the magic during the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of your code changes between perl 5.16 and perl 5.18. I didn't research it further to know if the change was a fix or an implementation.

```
$ PATH=/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.16/bin:$PATH

$ grep -E '^java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.*timeStampLastSeekPoint' messages |     perl -ne 'if (/timeInNanos=(\d+), timeStampLastSeekPoint=(\d+)/) { printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", $1, $2, $2 - $1) }' | head -5
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 0
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 0

$ PATH=/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.18/bin:$PATH

$ grep -E '^java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.*timeStampLastSeekPoint' messages |     perl -ne 'if (/timeInNanos=(\d+), timeStampLastSeekPoint=(\d+)/) { printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", $1, $2, $2 - $1) }' | head -5
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 1
1500629929661000010 1500629929661000011 1
```